# Sorting algorithm Visualization

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to show the result of the completion of each inner for loop but when executed, it directly shows the final result.

```
const reframe = ()=>{
  ele = document.querySelectorAll(".element");
  ele.forEach((el,index) =>{
  el.style.height = `${arr[index]}px`;
 });
}

const selection_sort= ()=>{
    for( let j = 0 ; j< n-1 ; j++){
        for(let k = j+1 ; k<n ;k++){
            if(arr[j]>arr[k])
            {
                let temp = arr[j];
                arr[j]   = arr[k];
                arr[k]   =  temp;
                console.log(arr);
            }
            reframe();
        }

    }

}
```

[image]

The final output.. I need to change the visualization for every loop

Comment: Do you mean, you want that `console.log` to trigger after every inner loop?

Comment: No.. I need the visual representation to change for every step

Comment: Then for every reframe, you need to create a new element, set the height and push it to the element container.

Comment: Each time you launch the "reframe" function, you should wait some time to actually see the height changing for each cycle. Doing it this way the dom elements will be rendered just once, when all the code has been executed